# How to fix undefined error while trying to get subscriptionId from VRFCoordinatorV2?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I was following along with a [Patrick Collins tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ) when I came across an error while trying to view the `subscriptionId` from inside `transactionReceipt`.

This is my code:

```js
    const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
    const { deploymentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
    const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");
    require("dotenv").config();

    module.exports = async function ({ deployments, getNamedAccounts }) {
        const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
        const { deploy, log } = deployments;
        let VRFCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;
        const chainId = network.config.chainId;
        const VRF_SUB_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("2");
        const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"];
        const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"];
        const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"];
        const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"];

        if (deploymentChains.includes(network.name)) {
            const VRFCoordinator = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock");
            VRFCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinator.address;
            const transactionResponse = await VRFCoordinator.createSubscription();
            const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
            subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
            await VRFCoordinator.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_AMOUNT);
        } else {
            VRFCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["VRFCoordinatorAddress"];
            subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"];
        }

        const args = [
            VRFCoordinatorV2Address,
            entranceFee,
            gasLane,
            subscriptionId,
            callbackGasLimit,
            interval,
        ];
        const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: args,
            waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations,
        });
        if (!deploymentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
            await verify(raffle.address, args);
        }
        log("----------------------------------------------");
    };

    module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"];
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: this is the error im getting]

I've noticed that the error is coming from the line `subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;`, can anyone tell me why this is happening?

This is the smart contract code:

```js
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
    import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/AutomationCompatible.sol";

    /*errors*/
    error Raffle__NotEnoughETHentered();
    error Raffle__TransferFailed();
    error Raffle__NotOpen();
    error Raffle__upKeepNotNeeded(uint256 balance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

    contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
        enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
        }

        uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
        address payable[] private s_players;
        uint256 private s_requestId;
        bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
        uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
        uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
        uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
        uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;
        VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfcoordinator;

        /*lottery variables*/
        address private s_recentWinner;
        RaffleState private s_raffleState;
        uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
        uint256 private immutable i_interval;

        /*Events*/
        event RaffleEnter(address payable indexed player);
        event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 requestId);
        event WinnerPicked(address indexed Winner);

        /*Functions*/
        constructor(
            address VRFCoordinatorV2,
            uint256 entranceFee,
            bytes32 gasLane,
            uint64 subscriptionId,
            uint32 callbackGasLimit,
            uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(VRFCoordinatorV2) {
            i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
            i_vrfcoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(VRFCoordinatorV2);
            i_gasLane = gasLane;
            i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
            s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
            s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
            i_interval = interval;
        }

        function enterRaffle() public payable {
            if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
                revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHentered();
            }
            if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
                revert Raffle__NotOpen();
            }

            s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
            emit RaffleEnter(payable(msg.sender));
        }

        function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /*checkData*/
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /*performData*/) {
            bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
            bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp > i_interval);
            bool hasBalance = (address(this).balance > 0);
            bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
            upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        }

        function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
            (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
            if (!upkeepNeeded) {
                revert Raffle__upKeepNotNeeded(
                    address(this).balance,
                    s_players.length,
                    uint256(s_raffleState)
                );
            }
            s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
            s_requestId = i_vrfcoordinator.requestRandomWords(
                i_gasLane,
                i_subscriptionId,
                REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
                i_callbackGasLimit,
                NUM_WORDS
            );
            emit RequestedRaffleWinner(s_requestId);
        }

        function fulfillRandomWords(
            uint256 /*requestId*/,
            uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
            uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
            address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
            s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
            (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
            s_players = new address payable[](0);
            s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
            if (!success) {
                revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
            }
            emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
            s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        }

        /*view/pure functions*/
        function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
            return i_entranceFee;
        }

        function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
            return s_players[index];
        }

        function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
            return s_recentWinner;
        }

        function getRaffleState() public view returns (RaffleState) {
            return s_raffleState;
        }

        function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint32) {
            return NUM_WORDS;
        } 

        function getNumOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
            return s_players.length;
        }

        function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
            return s_lastTimeStamp;
        }

        function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint16) {
            return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There may be no error in the subscription part.
Can you provide the smart contract code, and constructor part, as you may pass arguments in incorrect order?

Comment: hey i've added the smart contract code. can u check it. thank you! @
Al-Qa'qa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the `0` inside of `subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;`, which probably means that the `events` object is not returning the expected value, to see what is being returned try adding a `console.log(transactionReceipt)` and then a `console.log(transactionReceipt.events)` object.

If the second `console.log` doesn't return an object with the variables that were emitted in the event, try  `console.log(transactionReceipt.logs)`. If you see the expected values here, take it a step further by trying to access the variable directly:

`subscriptionId = BigInt(transactionReceipt.logs[0].topics[1])`

The change in syntax might be due to varying `ethers` versions since [ethers v6](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/) seems to have introduced a massive amount of changes from the previous version.

Comment: yea it worked for me . I found the subId variable in {console.log(transactionReceipt.logs[0].args)} and further by doing {transactionReceipt.logs[0].args.subId} i got it solved. and yeah its also working the other way ie. {transactionReceipt.logs[0].topics[1]}. Thanks alot! . [update in deploy code]: i was getting another error with the line {VRFCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinator.address;} so, i changed it to {VRFCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinator.target;} and its working.

Comment: @Gautam no problem glad to help! Make sure to mark the answer as solved whenever you get a chance!

Comment: could u also plz check this out https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/154542/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-checkupkeep