# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checkUpkeep')

Tags: blockchain, hardhat, mocha, chai

i'm getting this error while testing patrick collins smart-contract-lottery project, below  is
the part where the error coming from.

```
    describe("checkUpkeep", async function () {
          it("returns false if no one sends ETH", async function () {
              await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [parseInt(interval) + 1]);
              await network.provider.send("evm_mine", []);
              const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep("0x");
              assert(!upkeepNeeded);
          });
      });
```

the relevant code of function from the contract is down below.

```
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__upKeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        s_requestId = i_vrfcoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(s_requestId);
    }
```

when i remove callStatic it works well, i think the problrm is from callStatic. can anyone help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Ethers v6](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/) comes with some major changes to their syntax, `<contract>.staticCall.<function>` is the way for v5, but the syntax for v6 looks like this:

[image]

For example:

```js
it("Should transfer the funds to the owner", async function () {
        const { lock, unlockTime, lockedAmount, owner } = await loadFixture(
          deployOneYearLockFixture
        );
        await time.increaseTo(unlockTime);
        await lock.staticCall.withdraw();
      });
```

This test returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withdraw')`

```js
it("Should transfer the funds to the owner", async function () {
        const { lock, unlockTime, lockedAmount, owner } = await loadFixture(
          deployOneYearLockFixture
        );
        await time.increaseTo(unlockTime);
        await lock.withdraw.staticCall();
      });
```

And this test doesn't fail